# Script js not updating in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I already have web app develop with laravel, after i edited some line on my javascript file, and save it, it doesn't change when i check on my browser.
i put my javascript file on public folder.

```
@push('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('public/myJavascript.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

i already tried clear cache on browser, but it doesn't work as well

this app already on live server, i code it via winSCP.
I have no idea what was going on here, Thank you in advance

Comment: share console logs !

Comment: What error you have in console?

Comment: Do you have `@stack('scripts')` in the parent view?

Comment: i got nothing in console @knubbe

Comment: nothing in console @WaleedMuaz

Comment: i do have @stack('scripts') in parent view @geertjanknapen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it already solved now, i need to run this command below

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

thank you

Comment: If you could provide details as to how you've solved the problem, it could help others to an answer when facing the same problem.